# How can you make images move as I scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, animation

I want to make a website that contains images. I want the images to move as I scroll. So, if I'm moving down they should go a little bit up, if I move up, they should move a little bit down.

Here is an example to showcase what I'm talking about. Go to the very bottom to see what I mean.

https://www.twigspaper.com

Comment: try lax.js https://github.com/alexfoxy/lax.js

Comment: In case it helps, what you're describing is called Parallax Scrolling. There are already a load of questions regarding parallax scroll effects. May be take a look at a few of them.

Comment: @phuzi No, I'm not talking about parallax scrolling, please see the link that I've provided in order to see what I mean, and please scroll down to the very bottom.

Comment: If you're talking about the images towards the bottom of the page that move as you scroll, then this appears to be a variant of parallax scrolling. There appears to be a non-linear animation effect in place but I would still cal this a parallax scroll effect.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the variable document.body.onscroll like this:

```
function func() {}
document.body.onscroll = func;
```